# tinymce-rails custom skin not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tinymce, tinymce-rails

I'm using tinymce-rails gem (version 3.5.9) and wish to add a custom skin [thebigreason](http://thebigreason.com/blog/2008/09/29/thebigreason-tinymce-skin)

My question is two pronged I suppose:

1. The tinymce-rails wiki says to add the skin to:

   ```
   tinymce/themes/advanced/skins/
   ```

   So I dropped the 'bigreason' folder into the following directory:

   ```
   app/assets/tinymce/themes/advanced/skins/
   ```

   In tinymce.yml config file I did as instructed and loaded my skin:

   ```
   theme : "advanced"
   skin : "thebigreason"
   ```

   But the original theme still exists.  I've restarted the server
2. Where does this gem keep all the files!  I had to create the tinymce folder mentioned above. A bit of a generic question but I will want to adjust the contents css etc later

EDIT:

Forgot to mention, application.css contains the following:

```
*= require /tinymce/themes/advanced/skins/thebigreason/content.css
*= require /tinymce/themes/advanced/skins/thebigreason/ui.css
*= require /tinymce/themes/advanced/skins/thebigreason/dialog.css
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did figure it out now: I had the default skin defined below.

To (slightly) redeem myself this is how it's done:

Place skin here:

```
app/assets/stylesheets/tinymce/themes/advanced/skins/{skin_folder_with_css_files}
```

and the config will do everything else.  Include a path to this skin in applications.css for asset compilation later:

```
*= require /stylesheets/tinymce/themes/advanced/skins/{skin_folder}/{css_file.css}
```

One issue that I see is that some skins have body tags with margins, header definitions and so on which is bound to wreak havoc with the Rails asset pipeline .

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for.